# TFS2012 on Windows Server 2008 config error

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008

I am attempting to install Team Foundation Server 2012 on a computer and am coming up with a compatibility error. The .exe is - Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 (x86 and x64) - Web Installer (English) that was taken from the msdn website. Below is the servers properties and the error message. Any ideas what is causing the issue and whether it is an issue with the Server or if I need a older version of TFS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the installer is corrupted.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/521b8639-399c-4e9c-bb69-5b97289ead8b/

Comment: Betty, I am attempting a install of TFS2012 on a remote server(we'll call it the dev server). The database I will be using (SQL Server 2008 R2) is on a separate server. Do you know if the admin account I use to log on to the dev server to install TFS needs to also have admin rights to the database I am connecting to? Thanks

Comment: I believe you need admin on the database server, not just the specific database during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was with the .exe file. At some point it became corrupt. I was able to use a different .exe (same tfs2012 web installer) and it worked fine.